# Error of "xsl:stylesheet" is invalid

Tags: xml, xslt, wix

I am using WIX for some installer and need to filter out certain exe files. Not expert of xsl file but I copied it from some previous project and assumed the syntax is correct. However, I always get this error says: "The document element name: 'xsl:stylesheet' is invalid. A windows Installer XML souce file must use 'Wix' as the document element name."

Here is the xsl file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
            xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
            xmlns:wi="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">


<xsl:output method="xml"
            indent="yes"
            encoding="utf-8"/>

<!--List of files which are defined statically in the solution-->
<xsl:key name="kCompsToRemove"
         match="wi:Component[wi:File/@Source='$(var.StageDirXFire)\ServerComponents\Commend.Common.Server.DriverService.exe']"                  
         use="@Id" />

<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*[self::wi:Component or self::wi:ComponentRef]
                    [key('kCompsToRemove', @Id)]" />

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: It seems like the XSLT file is not the problem, but the way it is referenced in your WIX project. WIX seems to load it as a .wxs file instead of a .xsl file. How do you reference the XSLT file?

Comment: Any updates on this?  I'm having the exact same issue.